# Ajax data post in ASP.NET Core 1 doesn't pass values

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

How do I POST data using Ajax when passing data from data field? The issue *seems* to be that my data doesn't get posted to the controller correctly because I have tried to replace the actual data-attribute with hard-coded numbers and still cant POST that number. Here is my ajax call:

```
                $(".js-toggle-attendance")
                .click(function(e) {
                    var button = $(e.target);
                    $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/attendances/",
                            method: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            data: 'gigId : button.attr("data-gig-id")',
                            dataType: "json"
                        })
                        .done(function() {
                            button
                                .removeClass("btn-default")
                                .addClass("btn-info")
                                .text("Going");
                        })
                        .fail(function() {
                            alert("Something failed!");
                        });
                });
        });
</script>
```

my controller action is as follows:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Attend(AttendanceDTO dto)
    {
```

and the AttendanceDTO is just a simple Data transfer object class:

```
    public class AttendanceDTO
{
    public int GigId { get; set; }
}
```

I have tried the following variants for the data method, and what is in Chrome Dev Tools/Network Request payload is as follows (I am clicking button with id=1):

```
    data: 'gigId : button.attr("data-gig-id")'--> gigId : button.attr("data-gig-id")
    data: { "gigId": button.attr("data-gig-id") } --> gigId=1
    data: button.attr("data-gig-id") --> 1      No Properties
    data: "2" --> 2    No Properties
```

In all cases, debugging the controller actions shows the dto field as 0.

**UPDATE:**
I added the [FromBody] tag and JSON stringified the data, and the correct data seems to be posting now. However, the fail method above keeps executing all the time. I updated the code to pull the error message as below:

```
                $(".js-toggle-attendance")
                .click(function(e) {
                    var button = $(e.target);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/attendances/",
                        method: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ "gigId": button.attr("data-gig-id") }),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function() {
                            button
                                .removeClass("btn-default")
                                .addClass("btn-info")
                                .text("Going");
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            var x = error;
                            alert("Something failed!");
                        }
                    });
                });
```

And the error message that I Was able to capture from Chrome Dev Tools:

```
error = Object {readyState: 4, responseText: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK"
```

**UPDATE TO FIX ISSUE ABOVE:**
Just had to remove dataType: "json" because server was not pushing back json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not declare your action parameter as `[FromBody]`.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Attend([FromBody]AttendanceDTO dto)
{
}
```

should do the trick. As for the data, the `{ "gigId": button.attr("data-gig-id") }` should be the right format, though you may need to convert it to json string before passing it.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue by adding GigId: button.attr("data-gig-id"). able to fix it 
this might help

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $(".js-toggle-attendance").click(function (e) {
            var button = $(e.target);

            $.post("/api/attendances", { GigId: button.attr("data-gig-id") })
                .done(function() {
                    button
                        .removeClass("btn-default")
                        .addClass("btn-info")
                        .text("Going");
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    alert("something failed !");`enter code here`
                });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else, I had a `DTO` without a parameter-less constructor and pre ASP.NET Core used to throw an exception on that, whereas ASP.NET Core doesn't, it just gives you a null object